# How do you deal with Recursive Relationships N:M, in Database Relational Schema

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, entity-relationship

When we have a **N:M Recursive Relationship** what is the best way to create the **relational schema**?

In various books I searched they analyze recursive relationships of 1:1 and 1:N but for N:M there is almost nothing.

Should I treat it like a new Relationship like we do in traditional N:M non-recursive relationships?

For example in this recursive relationship is it better to:

***A.Create a new relationship***

INVITE(**InviterId,InviteeId**,AcceptanceDate,InvitationDate) - in bold the **Primary Keys** . In this case they are also foreign keys.

////

***B. Include this relationship in the Person Entity***

PERSON(**Id**,Password,InviterId,InviteeId,AcceptanceDate,InvitationDate).

///

[image]

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "recursive relationship"--in terms of the state of a database or DBMS--its DDL & table values?

Comment: You mean those 2 columns are the columns of a single composite CK (possibly a PK). And if two people can have more than one commitment then that CK has more columns.

Answer (score 1):

Definitions are recursive, not relationships/associations. You seem to be talking about FK (foreign key) cycles or the special case of that where a FK references its own table. A FK constraint says values appear elsewhere as PK/UNIQUE. Alternatively, that values that satisfy one relationship satisfy another in just one way. There's nothing special about this from a relational design standpoint. Most SQL DBMSs are needlessly poor when the explicit/declared FK graph is not a tree.

Whether you could or should combine your tables depends on the information modeling & database design method you are using plus relational database design principles. There are many different "traditions". Find & follow a published academic textbook on information modeling, the relational model & database design. (Dozens are free online, also slides & courses.) PS Information & manuals on a tool to manage designs does not constitute an introduction on how to design.

The diagram you give is a Chen original true pure ER (entity relationship) diagram. Under that method you can't combine your entity & relationship into a relationship because an entity needs to have its own box & table. But you could in the relational model & in pseudo-ER methods & products that don't use diamonds in their diagrams & in methods that allow more choice in mapping from Chen diagrams.